# How can I maintain references to multiple compiled regex expressions

Tags: regex, go

I’d like to precompile more than one regex expression and store the references in variables, but I am running into a problem.

It seems when I call the `regexp.Compile()` method a second time, I don’t get a new reference.  Its point to the first.

In the example below, only r2 should return “true”.    How can I get a unique reference each time I call `regexp.Compile()`?

https://play.golang.org/p/KJJbytSZddJ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    r1, _ := regexp.Compile(`(/api)(/v\d+)/devices`)
    r2, _ := regexp.Compile(`(/api)(/v\d+)/devices/\w+`)
    
    fmt.Println(r1.MatchString("/api/v1/devices/1"))
    fmt.Println(r2.MatchString("/api/v1/devices/1"))
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you get the same reference? They are two different compiled regular expressions, and the string matches both.

Comment: When I use them independently, the behavior is correct.  The first one returns false and the second true.  With the above, code both are returning true.

Comment: @user3137124 I just tried that code and both return true even if I comment out r2 or r1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you want the following code. Use regex anchors to prevent the first one from matching too much. Also use MustCompile at global scope because otherwise if you use Compile in a function it will run every function call. And you were ignoring the error return value anyway.

https://play.golang.org/p/tj3J_PSXNu1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var r1 = regexp.MustCompile(`^(/api)(/v\d+)/devices$`)
var r2 = regexp.MustCompile(`^(/api)(/v\d+)/devices/\w+$`)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(r1.MatchString("/api/v1/devices/1"))
    fmt.Println(r2.MatchString("/api/v1/devices/1"))
}
```

Comment: hmm... ok... this to seems work.  So my regex was bad.  Thanks for providing a working example.